Why are foster mothers used in creating genetically modified organisms?
In every source I have seen regarding creation of transgenic mammals, a foster mother is used for the womb instead of the mammal who produced the egg cell. See these sources: Jax Mouse Genome Informatics ScienceDirect LibreTexts
Therefore, my question is: Why is another animal used instead of simply using the biological mother as the foster mother? Is it some kind of immune reaction to the transgenic embryo? If so, wouldn't the foster mother have the same reaction?

Mortality during egg harvesting perhaps...? Please be aware of our requirement to show your research (into the question) when posting.

For humans, retrieving mature oocytes is a costly procedure involving anesthesia, a laparoscope, and other equipment. As unpleasant as it may be, it's much more cost effective to just euthanize the female then surgically collect her oocytes via laparotomy. Imagine a tiny anesthesized mouse on an operating table with an anatomist/surgeon(?) using the world's smallest laparoscope collecting oocytes with the most delicate suction equipment, supporting the mouse post-surgery and reimplanting the embryos after her recovery? That's almost science fiction!
